# Q: Subsetting a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a data set called newgss with a variable REALRINC that contains numeric values of income. I'm trying to create two subsets of it within the newgss df. One lowincome that would hold all income values <= 15000 and one highincome that holds all values > 15000. I've tried to modify some example codes I've found and have gotten errors. Here's an example of what I did to get all income > 15000 into a variable called highincome3.

```
newgss$highincome3 <- subset(newgss, REALRINC > 15000)
```

I get the following error for that code:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "highincome3", value = list(YEAR =
>   c(2006L,  :    replacement has 14625 rows, data has 46303

```
newgss$lowincome<- [newgss$REALRINC <= 15000]
```

This gives me TRUE and FALSE values when I look at `head(newgss$lowincome)`

Here's some more code that I've tried that didn't work:

```
newgss$lowincome<- [newgss$REALRINC <= 15000] 
newgss$lowincome[gss$REALRINC <= 15000] <- gss$REALRINC 
newgss$highincome[newgss$REALINC >= 15000]
newgss$highincome <- newgss[ which(REALINC>= 15000), ]
newgss$highincome2 <- subset(newgss, REALRINC>= 15000,select=REALRINC)
newgss$highincome3 <- subset(newgss, REALRINC > 15000)
```

Comment: `highincome3 <- subset(newgss, REALRINC > 15000)` might work. `newgss$highincome3` would be a column of `newgss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says  with `newgss$highincome3 <- subset(newgss, REALRINC > 15000)` you are trying to create an a column in dataset `newgss` that only has **46303** elements ( that means 46303 of your incomes are more than 15000). What you need to do is:

```
newgss1<-newgss[newgss$REALRINC >15000,]
newgss2<-newgss[newgss$REALRINC <=15000,]
```

Or:

```
newgss$income_level_gt15k<- [newgss$REALRINC <= 15000]
```

and then use the newly created variable income_level_gt15k to subset the data

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I'm looking for. I see what I was stuck on now.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

newgssLT15 <- filter(newgss, REALRINC < 15000)
newgssGT15 <- filter(newgss, REALRINC >= 15000)
```